# Form not getting submitted using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to validate user using oAuth 2.0 which works fine and am obtaining user information from google using jquery which I want to send to the next page. So to do that, I am making form programmatically using jQuery and submitting using same. But unfortunately, form is not getting submitted. I have seen various answers on stack-overflow and have tried to implement using that things but none of them is working.

Here is my code..

#### customButtonRender.js

```
function onSuccess(googleUser){
    
    console.log('Logged in as '+googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    submit_form(profile);
}


var submit_form = function(profile){

    console.log(profile.getId());
    console.log(profile.getName());
    console.log(profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log(profile.getEmail());

    var user_url = "localhost:8080/NUConnect_JSP/jsp/home.jsp";
    var val_form = $('<form data-ajax="false" method="POST" id="val_form"     action="' + user_url + '">'+
        '<input type="text" name="user_name" value="' + profile.getName() + '">'+
        '<input type="text" name="user_email" value="' + profile.getEmail() + '">'+
        '<input type="submit" name="user_submit" id="user_submit">'+
    '</form>');
    $('body').append(val_form);
    
    //    $("#val_form").submit();
    //    $("#val_form")[0].submit();
    //    $("#user_submit").click();
   document.getElementById("val_form").submit();

   console.log("After submit");

};
```

I have included *customButtonRender.js* file in head section.

As you can see I have tried various methods to submit form written in comments but none of them worked.

All the logs are printed successfully.

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX?

Comment: How to send data to a different page at the same time redirect to that page with that data using AJAX?

Comment: One tip I have is just put the form in the HTML but hidden. Then select the input and set its value onSuccess. Don't append form dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried to submit it without appending to the `body`? Just like `$(val_form).submit();` right after `var val_form = $(...);`? It works for me.

Comment: Tried that too but not working...

Comment: @VarunRaval That's strange :( That was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing if your data is not so confidential then pass that information in your url like this

```
window.location.href = "localhost:8080/NUConnect_JSP/jsp/home.jsp?user_name="+profile.getName()+"&user_email="+ profile.getEmail();
```

Comment: Yes, that's the last option I will try. Thanks for your response.